# JCombobox focusLost is not firing-why is that?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcombobox, focuslistener

I have a `JCombobox` in my code. I have added the `FocusLost event`. But it didn't fired anyway. I have tried lots of time but didn't find solution.

```
jcbItemType.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        jcbItemTypeFocusLost(evt);
    }
});

private void jcbItemTypeFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt)                                      
    {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("name=" + ((Component) evt.getSource()).getName());
        System.out.println("index=" + jcbItemType.getSelectedIndex());
    }
```

But nothing is printed in console. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) isn't proper Listener for [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), altogether with another [Listener(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) can creating endless loop (especially Editable JComboBox),
- [FocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) is asynchronous, sometimes is too hard to catch events is right orders especially in the cases that JComponents has added another [Listener(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) too

example how to listening for [Focus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) from derived `JTextField / JFormattedTextField`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox subComboBox;

    public ComboBoxTwo() {
        String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
        String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        mainComboBox.addFocusListener(fcsListener);
        add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        subComboBox = new JComboBox(subItems1);
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        subComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                System.out.println("Source  : mainComboBox");
            } else if (e.getSource() == subComboBox) {
                System.out.println("Source  : subComboBox");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTwo();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
//
    private FocusListener fcsListener = new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            dumpInfo(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            dumpInfo(e);
        }

        private void dumpInfo(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Source  : " + name(e.getComponent()));
            System.out.println("Opposite : " + name(e.getOppositeComponent()));
            System.out.println("Temporary: " + e.isTemporary());
            final Component c = e.getComponent();//works for editable JComboBox too
            if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((JFormattedTextField) c).selectAll();
                    }
                });
            } else if (c instanceof JTextField) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ((JTextField) c).selectAll();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private String name(Component c) {
            return (c == null) ? null : c.getName();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I have previously used `itemStateChanged` but it is problematic for my purpose and hence i want to use FocusLost event. Your example didn't work for me although you have comment as *//works for editable JComboBox too*. But it isn't working for me. Please advise. I am searching it for long time.

Comment: @sarwar026 in this form works as I expected, rest is noticed in my answer, use ItemListener for JComboBox, for example in the form as I posted here,

Comment: @sarwar026 simple I don't understood for why reason you have to required FocusListener, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 9):

I have found a very simple way to solve this.

The JComboBox default editor has an internal class BasicComboBoxEditor$BorderlessTextField that is the component that gets and loses focus.

It can be accessed simply by

```
Component component = comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();  
if (component instanceof JTextField) 
    JTextField borderlesstextfield = (JTextField) borderless;
```

Then add a focus listener like you would to any JTextField

```
borderlesstextfield.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() 
{
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
     {
     }
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) 
     {
     }
}});
```

Now you have a FocusListener that will respond as expected to gain and loss of focus for the ComboBox

Comment: This worked perfectly and should be the accepted answer since it is far less convoluted!

Comment: I agree with @Xerus this answer is way more understandable and deserves to be the accepted answer