# Select text by default in swing

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jtextarea

There is any way to automatically by default select text in `JTextField` and `JTextArea` when `focusGained` event occurs?

Comment: You should look @mKorbel answer from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293135/jcombobox-focuslost-is-not-firing-why-is-that/10293343#10293343

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just said how to do it -- focusGained event of a FocusListener.

You can then get the JComponent whose focus has been gained via FocusEvent's `getSource()` method and then call the `selectAll()` method on it.

Something like:

```
FocusAdapter selectAllFocusAdapter = new FocusAdapter() {
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    final JTextComponent tComponent = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        tComponent.selectAll();
      }
    });
    tComponent.selectAll();
  }
};

myJTextField.addFocusListener(selectAllFocusAdapter);
otherJTextField.addFocusListener(selectAllFocusAdapter);
myTextArea.addFocusListener(selectAllFocusAdapter);
```

Comment: @mKorbel: thanks! Answer edited, and 1+ to your linked answer.

Comment: @Ricardo this answer to your question, notice, for JTextArea couldn't be selectAll the proper methods, I'd be moving with Caret to the end of text

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need:

```
jTextField1.selectAll();
```

More below:

```
jTextField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if(jTextField1.getText().equals(initialText))
                //jTextField1.setText("");
                jTextField1.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(jTextField1.getText().equals(""))
                jTextField1.setText("whatever");
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 quite good :-) but common issue is about [Focus is asynchronous, required invokeLater in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293343/714968)

Answer (score 5):

Are you expecting something like

```
    class MyFocusTextField extends JTextField {
    {
        addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                FocusTextField.this.select(0, getText().length());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                FocusTextField.this.select(0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 quite good :-) but common issue is about [Focus is asynchronous, required invokeLater in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10293343/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel I agree with you. Thanks.