# How to implement FocusListener to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, focuslistener

I have created new class which extends JTextArea and have implemented that class with FocusListener but the code inside the focusLost method is not getting executed. Whats the cause?

```
protected class JDynamicTextArea extends JTextArea implements FocusListener { 
    public JDynamicTextArea() { 
        super(); 
        addFocusListener(this); 
    } 
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) { } 
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) { 
        System.out.println("Focus lost"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you registered the class as a focus listener using addFocusListener?

Comment: yes, i have added focus listener inside the constructor.

Comment: I think you will need to provide example code then

Comment: protected class JDynamicTextArea extends JTextArea implements FocusListener    {    public JDynamicTextArea()    {    super();    addFocusListener(this);    }    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)    {  }    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)    {    System.out.println("Focus lost");    }    }

Comment: Do I need to implement keylistener as well?

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't immediately assume the AWT event thread was the issue, but based on [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542410/focuslistener-on-editable-jcombobox-not-firing/15546211), I'm wondering if you are constructing your JDynamicTextArea in the AWT event thread (since Swing objects fail in mysterious ways if used in any other thread).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was thinking that if I transfer focus on tab keypress.

Comment: @user2113996 `KeyListener` is NEVER a good choice for trying to transfer focus.  You need to take advantage of the [focus transferal system](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: typically, low-level listeners like focusListener are so hard to get correct that _not_ using them is the best option most of the time. So the real question is: what do you want to achieve? Chances are that you can do so by some higher level methods (f.i. by binding focus transfer keys, as @MadProgrammer suggested)

Comment: btw: JSomething are _not_ meant to be subclassed, but used as-are. As they already provide a feature to adding a listener, there's no need to subclass just to add a ... listener :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I need to store some data inside textarea while instantiating its object, I am creating it dynamically so need that information for further use.

Comment: still doesn't sound like a legitimate reason for subclassing - anyway, best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck.

Comment: @kleopatra Some values are associated with the JTextArea which are only available while instantiating that object.

Comment: as they can't fall fall from open sky, they most probably are available to the instantiating code as well - so still no reason for subclassing ;-)

Comment: it seems you didn't understand the problem. And it is very big code in my project so i cant' put a SSCCE, but i will try to put one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work just fine for me...

Click the second text field and you should see the focus lost event fire.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFocus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFocus();
    }

    public TestFocus() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            add(new JScrollPane(new JDynamicTextArea()));
            add(new JTextField(10));
        }

    }

    protected class JDynamicTextArea extends JTextArea implements FocusListener {

        public JDynamicTextArea() {
            super(10, 10);
            addFocusListener(this);
        }

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Focus gained");
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Focus lost");
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated with key focus transfer**

To reenable keyboard transfer focus, you need to add the following to the constructor

```
Set<KeyStroke> strokes = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(Arrays.asList(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed TAB")));
setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, strokes);
strokes = new HashSet<KeyStroke>(Arrays.asList(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift pressed TAB")));
setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, strokes);
```

Comment: ehhh ... me telling the newbie to _not_ subclass and you old hand doing it _twice_ for no viable reason at all :-(

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry Kleo, I'm not, I'm trying to demonstrate that there code works with a running example in some small attempt to find out what it is they are trying to achieve. I got the fact that they want to reinstate the transfer focus keys out of the OP

Comment: @kleopatra Now you've told me I the past I shouldn't use setPreferredSize, so the only way to provide suitable sizing hints is to override getPreferredSize ... Now, if I follow your suggestions, I can't possible ever create anything in Swing ;) - Seriously, I understand and support your point