# Prevent selections of the current selection from notifying listeners in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, events, jcombobox

I would like to prevent an event from being fired when a user selects a value already selected in a `JComboBox`.

For instance, assume I have a `JComboBox` whose model has the following values:

- Cat
- Dog
- Fish
- Bird
- Snake

The currently selected value is "Cat". I would like to prevent an Listeners from being notified if the user selects "Cat" again, whilst "Cat" is already selected.

I have tried to implement this by adding a check in the `setSelectedItem(Object)` in the model. This however did not work.

My next assumption is that if I want this functionality, I will need to subclass `JComboBox` and override it's `setSelectedItem(Object)` and `contentsChanged(ListDataEvent)` functions.

Given the documentation for `contentsChanged(ListDataEvent)` however, I am hesitant to override it. As such my question for all of you:

**Is there a better way to get this desired functionality that doesn't require sub classing `JComboBox` and overriding it's `setSelectedItem(Object)` and `contentsChanged(ListDataEvent)` functions?**

Comment: *"I would like to prevent an action event from being fired.."*  Why?  Or rather:  Why not just ignore it in that case?  Seems like you've put the wagon before the horse.

Comment: It's easy, create one variable holding the selected value, after next selection, compare it with the selected value, it they are equals, *do nothing*, else, assign the selected value to it and *do your action*.

Comment: These JComboBox's are used to set values in other objects, which themselves will fire off additional events. The other problem is I was not aware this would happen until just recently, so my code doesn't test for this. Additionally, my model is such that it has "disabled" values. If I can find a way to do this, I can also prevent selection of these "disabled" values without that additional test everywhere.

Comment: @Azad this still results in the event being fired, I would like to prevent it from even being fired.

Comment: @Legowaffles: This is not possible, as swing components based on *object* and *event*, tell me, how do you know the selected value without using an event? You can't. Events creates for this reason.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I'm disagree, thanks - hehehe Seems like you've put the wagon before the horse. :-), yes I love that ..... :-)

Comment: @Azad I fear I have not exactly been clear as to my intent. Hopefully the edits make it more clear.

Comment: there are another sado_maso, to to add ListSelectionListener to derived JList from JComboBox, then is required to use Swing Action and to override isEnabled(),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to prevent an action event from being fired when a user
>   selects a value already selected in a JComboBox.

- use [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html),
- wrap code into `if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {` as is shown, described in Oracle tutorial
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10293343/714968)

Comment: As per the original, question text, this is exactly the answer. Unfortunately, my intent was poorly communicated, so this does not exactly solve my problem.

Comment: +1 for your answer that IMO *still* answers the actual need, if not the ..question.

Comment: 1. see my comment to your question, 2. don't do that JComboBox is compound JComponent, fall apart out like beads, 3. re_read comment by @Andrew Thompson - Seems like you've put the wagon before the horse. 4. don't to simulate ItemListener

Comment: Actually, I just did some further reading. It looks like this will exactly solve my problem. I was under the impression that it would have a state of `ItemEvent.SELECTED` even if they reselected the current value.

As such, marking this as the answer. Thank you.